# youtube comments form in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

when you writing some comments on Youtube videos using mobile phone, at first,

it seems one line.

but when it is 2 lines because of length

the container height has also expanded

how to implement kind of those things?

what I currently do is pretty normal.

```
Container(child: TextFormField(
          //usual codes
)),
```

Answer (score 0):

keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline

This Enables The keyboard to be multilined and increase its
Size

Comment: I currently using keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword     because some samsung keyboards are not working at all (it is known bugs on flutter github also) if I do not set like this

Comment: Then maybe , expands : true , may help

Comment: thanks but it also not works it hasn`t expanded height of container